# How to find class name from inspected code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, oracle-apex

When I inspected my web page I got this code

```
<li id="SR_R1_tab" class="t-Tabs-item a-Tabs-before a-Tabs-selected is-active" aria-controls="SR_R1" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
```

It is an oracle apex tabular region's sub region. I want to perform some css modifications and javascript actions in this class(sub regions of tabular region). How to find the exact class from this inspected code?. Should I use the class 't-Tabs-item' or 't-Tabs-item a-Tabs-before a-Tabs-selected is-active' ?

Comment: No need for classes, you can just use the id `SR_R1_tab` which should be unique on the whole document.

Comment: Thank @str . I want a javascript action too.. I want to set 'aria-selected' property value to 'true' using js. So I tried :  $("#SR_R1_tab").aria-selected('true');     but it didn't worked. what is wrong with this code?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This element has 4 css classes:

- t-Tabs-item
- a-Tabs-before
- a-Tabs-selected
- is-active

In the debugger, you need to observe what each class does to your UI and you can decide which class to override.

Example: if you want to change the styling for each element, you will probably have to override `t-Tabs-item`:

```
.t-Tabs-item {
  background: red;
}
```

But if you only want to change the appearance of the selected item, then you will  probably have to override `a-Tabs-selected`. In that case you should also add the more generic `.t-Tabs-item` class in order to avoid side effects.

```
.t-Tabs-item.a-Tabs-selected {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you . I want a javascript action too.. I want to set 'aria-selected' property value to 'true' using js. So I tried : $("#SR_R1_tab").aria-selected('true'); but that didn't worked for me. what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("SR_R1_tab").setAttribute("aria-selected", true);`

Answer (score 1):

The `li` element you posted has the class attribute:

```
class="t-Tabs-item a-Tabs-before a-Tabs-selected is-active"
```

This means it has the following class names:

```
t-Tabs-item 
a-Tabs-before 
a-Tabs-selected 
is-active
```

If you want to target only this `li`, by class name, and considering no other HTML elements have the same exact class `t-Tabs-item a-Tabs-before a-Tabs-selected is-active`, use this class name for selection:

```
.t-Tabs-item.a-Tabs-before.a-Tabs-selected.is-active { ... }
```

If you want to select any element which has the class name `t-Tabs-item`, use it as a selector, but consider that if other HTML elements in your page have this class, your selection would return multiple elements.

As per @[str](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906113/str)'s comment to your question, if you want to target this specific `li` element, it's best to use an `id` selector:

```
#SR_R1_tab  { ... }
```

Comment: I want a javascript action too.. I want to set 'aria-selected' property value to 'true' using js. So I tried : $("#SR_R1_tab").aria-selected('true'); but it didn't worked. what is wrong with this?